# Error converting SQL result to string

Tags: php, mysqli

Done this hundred of times before but this one is really throwing me out. As you can see the `$value` is not converted to string; but the `echo` before `$result .=` outputs just fine as you can see in the log. The `var_dump` also looks fine to me. I also tried `(string)$value`. Can anyone shed some light ?

PHP CODE:

```
  if ($result = $query->get_result()) {

    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        var_dump($data);
        echo $value;
        $result .= "<div class='post modelVariant'>".$value."</div>";
      }
    }

  mysqli_close($MySQLi);
  } else {
  mysqli_close($MySQLi);
  }
```

CONSOLE LOG:

```
array(1) {
["model_variant"]=>
string(3) "9.0"
}

9.0
```

> **Recoverable fatal error**:  Object of class mysqli_result could
>   not be converted to string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use variable `$result` both to concatenate string
`$result .= "<div class='post modelVariant'>".$value."</div>";` and for storing result from MySQL query `$result = $query->get_result()`.